# How do I specify unmarshall types with JSON encode in Terraform?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, unmarshalling

I am working on building a fargate cluster and am having difficulties following the documentation for the aws_ecs_task_definition section (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition)

```
│ Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ContainerDefinition.Cpu of type int64
│ 
│   with aws_ecs_task_definition.app,
│   on ecs.tf line 40, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "app":
│   40:   container_definitions = jsonencode([
│   41:     {
│   42:       "name": "${var.prefix}",
│   43:       "image": "${var.app_image}",
│   44:       "cpu": "256",
│   45:       "memory": "${var.fargate_memory}",
│   46:       "networkMode": "awsvpc",
│   47:       "logConfiguration": {
│   48:           "logDriver": "awslogs",
│   49:           "options": {
│   50:             "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.ecs.name}",
│   51:             "awslogs-region": "${var.region}",
│   52:             "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
│   53:           }
│   54:       },
│   55:       "environment": [
│   56:         {"name": "ENV_RUNNER_SLEEP_SECS", "value": "${var.app_env_runner_sleep_secs}"}
│   57:       ]
│   58:     }
│   59:   ])
```

The error is pointing to the value for CPU. This would normally be another variable but I'm just testing out inputs to try and get it to pass. Annoyingly enough, if I set the value to a number, I get a different error: `cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field KeyValuePair.Environment.Value of type string`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second error is from another field - number is correct for the cpu.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your analysis of the first error is correct: it is due to `cpu` having to be an integer / number / int64. That means you need to specify it as `"cpu": 256`.

The second error then tells you not to look at `ContainerDefinition.Cpu` but `KeyValuePair.Environment.Value` which is the `"environment": [ ... ]` section. The problem here is that keys and values have to be `string`s and even though you write `"${var.app_env_runner_sleep_secs}"` terraform still outputs a number despite the `"` surrounding it. To fix that you need to put a `tostring` around the argument: `"value": "${tostring(var.app_env_runner_sleep_secs)}"`.

Note that additionally depending on your terraform version it is a lot shorter and cleaner to write e.g. `"awslogs-region": var.region` by removing the `"${...}"` in all places.

Comment: Thanks! The cpu does still need to be a number so I'm wrapping the variable (which comes in as a string) in the tonumber function. I'm pretty new to tf so the Go error was a bit of an unexpected curve ball.

Comment: @Rhinosaurus completely relatable, getting direct golang errors instead of anything that is a bit more understandable is certainly unexpected and always feels like something is completely broken :D